# How can I enable WS-RM (version 1.2) with NuSOAP client

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, ws-reliablemessaging

Can enable I enable WS-RM (version 1.2) with NuSOAP client just like below? I tried this, but I cannot receive data from the API. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$client = new nusoap_client($api_link, array('reliable' => 1.2 , 'useWSA' => TRUE) );
```

Full Code:

```
try {
include_once 'WebServiceSOAP/lib/nusoap.php';

  $api_link = 'https://www.my-api.com/MYAPI.svc/SSL?wsdl';

  $acode = '###';

  $uname = '###';

  $ttype = '###';

  $ccode = '###';

  $hpass = '###';

  //setting xml request to api
  $credentials = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ezr="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EzremitAPI.Entities">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                   <tem:GetLocalRates>
                      <!--Optional:-->
                      <tem:credentials>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <ezr:AgentCode>'.$acode.'</ezr:AgentCode>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <ezr:HashedPassword>'.$hpass.'</ezr:HashedPassword>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <ezr:Username>'.$uname.'</ezr:Username>
                      </tem:credentials>
                      <!--Optional:-->
                      <tem:payincurcode>'.$ccode.'</tem:payincurcode>
                      <!--Optional:-->
                      <tem:transferType>'.$ttype.'</tem:transferType>
                   </tem:GetLocalRates>
                </soapenv:Body>
             </soapenv:Envelope>';
//creating soap object
$client = new nusoap_client($api_link, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2) );

$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$soapaction = "http://tempuri.org/IRateAPI/GetLocalRates";

$xmlobjs = $client->send($credentials, $soapaction);

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    exit();
 }
//print_r($client);
print_r($xmlobjs);

}
  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I'm not very good at PHP and SOAP. Above code may have errors. Could you please check the code and give me your comments. I have made some amendments after searching Google.

Also, can I run this on PHP 5.4.42? When I run above code, I get below error now.

Constructor error
HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Comment: Can you give us an example, how the xml request body should look like? As far as I know the nusoap library is outdated. Since PHP 5.0.1 the SOAP extension is fully implemented in php. You should use the native PHP Soap extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see the full code that I'm trying below.

Comment: Hi @Marcel Could you please have a look at my updated code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329194/soap-error-in-php-operationformatter-encountered-an-invalid-message-body and help me out. I have managed to finish the code, but I get an error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the answer to my above question, I found the solution with the help from @Marcel.

The answer to the question:

**This code is wrong, don't use it.**

```
$client = new nusoap_client($api_link, array('reliable' => 1.2 , 'useWSA' => TRUE) );
```

NuSoap client is outdated and not supporting to WS-RM. I had to use PHP inbuilt SOAP extension to get my project worked.

Full answer in here: [SOAP Error in PHP: OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329194/soap-error-in-php-operationformatter-encountered-an-invalid-message-body)

Thanks