# SOAP Error in PHP: OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

Original Question:

I'm trying to get data from `SOAP API wsdl` link. My code as below. But I get this error. Can anyone please help with this?

> Error Message: OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body.
>   Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetLocalRates' and
>   namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name
>   'soapenv:Envelope' and namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'

```
<?php
$api_link = 'https://www.my-api-link.com/RateAPI.svc/SSL?wsdl';

//setting xml request to api
$request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ezr="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EzremitAPI.Entities">
              <soapenv:Body>
                 <tem:GetLocalRates>
                     <tem:credentials>
                         <ezr:AgentCode>####</ezr:AgentCode>
                         <ezr:HashedPassword>####</ezr:HashedPassword>
                         <ezr:Username>####</ezr:Username>
                     </tem:credentials>
                     <tem:payincurcode>####</tem:payincurcode>
                     <tem:transferType>####</tem:transferType>
                 </tem:GetLocalRates>
              </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>';

try {
$client = new SoapClient($api_link, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'reliable' => 1.2 , 'useWSA' => TRUE ) );
$soapaction = "http://tempuri.org/IRateAPI/GetLocalRates";
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
// Apply WSA headers
$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'To', 'https://www.my-api-link.com/RateAPI.svc/SSL?wsdl', true);
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'Action', 'http://tempuri.org/IRateAPI/GetLocalRates', true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

$response = $client->GetLocalRates(new SoapVar($request, XSD_ANYXML));
print_r($response);

}
  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Edit 1 (Code amended as per to 1st comment)

**Results:**

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/faults:Receivera:InternalServiceFaultOperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetLocalRates' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'soapenv:Envelope' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetLocalRates' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'soapenv:Envelope' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
```

Edit 2:

**$client->__getTypes() Results:**

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(84) "struct EzCredential {
 string AgentCode;
 string HashedPassword;
 string Username;
}"
  [1]=>
  string(58) "struct ArrayOfCurrencyRate {
 CurrencyRate CurrencyRate;
}"
  [2]=>
  string(187) "struct CurrencyRate {
 decimal AgentMargin;
 string CurrencyCode;
 string CurrencyDescription;
 decimal FromAmount;
 decimal Rate;
 string RateType;
 decimal ToAmount;
 string Trantype;
}"
  [3]=>
  string(95) "struct GetLocalRates {
 EzCredential credentials;
 string payincurcode;
 string transferType;
}"
  [4]=>
  string(74) "struct GetLocalRatesResponse {
 ArrayOfCurrencyRate GetLocalRatesResult;
}"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "int char"
  [6]=>
  string(17) "duration duration"
  [7]=>
  string(11) "string guid"
}
```

**$client->__getFunctions() Results:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(62) "GetLocalRatesResponse GetLocalRates(GetLocalRates $parameters)"
}
```

Fixed: Used below instead of the XML envelope. Thanks a lot, @Marcel. You are a great saviour.

```
$requestParams = array( 'credentials' => array('AgentCode' => $acode,
                                               'HashedPassword' => $hpass,
                                               'Username' => $uname),
                  'payincurcode' => $ccode,
                  'transferType' => $ttype
              );

$response = $client->GetLocalRates( $requestParams );
```

Comment: First of all `reliable` and `useWSA` are no valid options for the soap client class. You can remove them. Further please add the option `'trace' => true`. This enables tracing the last request and response. In your catch block add `echo $client->__getLastResponse();` and tell us, what exactly the webservice returns as response.

Comment: Hi @Marcel I have added the results on my answer. Please have a look. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: The response clearly states, that your request body is not valid. This line: `$client->GetLocalRates(new SoapVar($request, XSD_ANYXML));` is wrong I guess. What kind of type the `GetLocalRates` function can take as param? You can find out by having a look at `$client->__getTypes()` and `$client->__getFunctions()`. The types declare the types you can send and get via the webservice. The functions show the function names, you can use via the webservice. Every function takes params. These params are declared in the types array.

Comment: @Marcel, Really sorry. I think the issue is in my XML Envelop. But I cannot think of how to fix that. This is the first time I'm working on SOAP call. Could you please give me a hint. I added the results above in my question.

Comment: Nope, the issue is not the envelope node. It 's the request itself. I 'll give you an example, how you can fix that. Thanks for the types and the functions. That was really useful.

Comment: @Marcel, Thanks a lot for all the help. I could fix the issue with your help. BTW, so this means that whole envelope thing that I was doing is wrong or is there a way to use XML envelope also?

Comment: I write an answer to your question. Be patient. ;)

Comment: The whole envelope thing is done by the soap client. You do not have to worry about it when using the native PHP soap library. There are some cases out there, that demand a more extensive approach. But this simple webservice call can be made with your approach or the even more cleaner oop approach I 've given as answer.

Comment: @Marcel Thanks a lot for the complete code. That is really helpful. I will try to amend my code in to oop way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you in advance that you have updated your question with the missing data. This example is a native php example that shows how to work with soap functions and types in an object orientated way.

**1. Types and classes**

As you can see in your types array, there are several types declared as *struct*. If you like to say so, structs can be called PHP classes. So lets make a single php class out of every struct.

```
class EzCredentialStruct
{
    public $AgentCode;

    public $HashedPassword;

    public $Username;

    public function getAgentCode() : string
    {
        return $this->AgentCode;
    }

    public function setAgentCode(string $AgentCode) : EzCredentialStruct
    {
        $this->AgentCode = $AgentCode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHashedPassword() : string
    {
        return $this->HashedPassword;
    }

    public function setHashedPassword(string $HashedPassword) : EzCredentialStruct
    {
        $this->HashedPassword = $HashedPassword;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername() : string
    {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $Username) : EzCredentialStruct
    {
        $this->Username = $Username;
        return $this;
    }
}

class GetLocalRatesStruct
{
    public $credentials;

    public $payincurcode;

    public $transferType;

    public function getCredentials() : EzCredentialStruct
    {
        return $this->credentials;
    }

    public function setCredentials(EzCredentialStruct $credentials) : GetLocalRatesStruct
    {
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPayincurcode() : string
    {
        return $this->payincurcode;
    }

    public function setPayincurcode(string $payincurcode) : GetLocalRatesStruct
    {
        $this->payincurcode = $payincurcode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTransferType() : string
    {
        return $this->transferType;
    }

    public function setTransferType(string $transferType) : GetLocalRatesStruct
    {
        $this->transferType = $transferType;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

These two classes are examples of all structs from your types array. So write down all your structs as classes. You will notice the benefit later.

**2. Soap Client and the classmap option**

Now, as we hace declared the used types of the webservice as classes, we can initiate the soap client. It is important to initiate the soap client with the right options. Always wrap up the client in a try/catch block.

```
try {
    $options = [
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'trace' => true,
        'classmap' => [
            'EzCredential' => 'EzCredentialStruct',
            'GetLocalRates' => 'GetLocalRatesStruct',
        ],
    ];

    $wsdl = 'path/to/the/webservice/endpoint?wsdl';

    $client = new \SoapClient(
        $wsdl,
        $options,
    );
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    // error handling
}
```

AS you can see there is a `classmap` key in the options array. The classmap routes types to specific php classes. In this example we only use the two example type classes we defined earlier. The soap client can now automatically create the xml string the webservice needs.

**3. Put it all together**

Now, as we have all we need for a proper soap request, our code should look as follows.

```
$credentials = (new EzCredentialStruct())
    ->setAgentCode($agentCode)
    ->setHashedPassword($hashedPassword)
    ->setUsername($username);

$request = (new GetLocalRatesStruct())
    ->setCredentials($credentials)
    ->setPayincurcode($code)
    ->setTransferType($transferType);

$result = $client->GetLocalRates($request);
```

**Conclusion**

At first glance, this approach may look like more work. But it makes sense to separate the types from the functions and programming classes for each struct the webservice declares. The call of the webservice function will be easier, because we only pass an object as a parameter. No more weird array constructs. Everything is in its place and can be reused.

PS: This code is not tested. It is not recommended using it in production. This code is intended as an example only. It may contain errors.